# Drupal login error message display on page by make new module

Tags: 7, users

I created the module and added the field in the user login block form for displaying error. I want to display the error in warning field instead of using `form_set_error()`. I am able to see the warning field in the login block. When I submit with error it did not display the error. Code is as under. I am missing how to refresh the value of form once it gets error.

```
function usermoved_form_user_login_block_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
$form['warning'] = array(
'#value' => t('oops'),
'#weight' => 11
);
$form['#submit'][] = 'usermoved_form_submit_code';
}


function usermoved_form_submit_code($form, &$form_state)
{
  global $user;
 if (!$user->uid) {
  $form['warning']['value']= "changed to something";

}

}
```

I have disabled the error in user.module as follows.

```
function user_login_final_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  global $user;
   if (!$user->uid) {
//form_set_error('name', t('Sorry, unrecognized username or password. <a  
    //href="@password">Have you forgotten your password?</a>', array('@password' => 
    //url('user/password'))));
}
}
```

Comment: it is not recommended to modify a core module directly as it can cause potential security risk or loss of functionality while upgrading, you could choose to remove `user_login_final_validate` from the `#validate` array of the form, please refer to modules such as [logintoboggan](http://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan/) to get better idea of how to implement custom validation without hacking the core module

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you **DO NOT CHANGE DRUPAL CORE** , if you want your custom validation use something like this

```
function usermoved_form_user_login_block_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
   $form['warning'] = array(
   '#value' => t('oops'),
   '#weight' => 11
   );
  $form['#submit'][] = 'usermoved_form_submit_code';
  $form['#validate'][] = 'yourcustomvalidationfunction';
     }
```

and in your custom validate fuction  put your error in `warning field`

```
 function   yourcustomvalidationfunction(&$form,&$form_state){
    if (your validation accure error) {
        $form['warning']['#value']= t('my error message that come in warning field') ;
       }
    }
```

or you can  **create and initial** `warning`  directly in validation function and not require create `warning field` in alter

Comment: Also see form_set_error()

Comment: @AyeshK,please read qustion again.:)

Comment: Oh, unlocked new badge: Stupidness.

Comment: :(.not say this. just say young Ayesh Karunaratne :)

Comment: @AyeshK , please sign this as accepted

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not the OP. However, in the second snippet, I think you will need to add the error message to #value. $form['warning'] expected to be an array (of form element's definitions) right ?

Comment: @AyeshK yes , I wrote it according to question, maybe I had better method ,but write it according you question. I edit it